# xgboost vs H2o Gradient Boosting

Tags: xgboost, h2o

I have a dataset having a large missing values (more than 40% missing). Genrated a model in xgboost and H2o gradient boosting - got a decent model in both cases. However, the xgboost shows this variable as one of the key contributors to the model but as per H2o Gradient Boosting the variable is not important. Does xgboost handle variables with missing values differently. All the configuration to both the models are exactly the same.

Answer (score 6):

Both missing value handling and variable importances are slightly different between the two methods. Both are treating missing values as information (i.e., they learn from them, and don't just impute with a simple constant). The variable importances are computed from the gains of their respective loss functions during tree construction. H2O uses squared error, and XGBoost uses a more complicated one based on gradient and hessian.

One thing you could check is the variance of the variable importances between different runs with different seeds, to see how stable each method is in terms of variable importances.

PS. If you have categoricals, then you're better off leaving the column as a factor for H2O, no need to do your own encoding. This can lead to a different effective count of columns vs XGBoost's dataset, so for column sampling, things will be different.